# How to re-run VSTS release with only a subset of steps (ex: just the tests)

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) releases (not builds) to push a websites to azure web app and then run a few casperJS tests against it. The releases steps are as follow:

1. Apply xdt transform to the specifc environment
2. Deploy Azure Web site
3. Run CasperJS test (invoke a batch file)

I sometime have reliability issue the tests (working on improving it) but I would like to be able to re-run/redeploy the VSTS release without having run step `1` and `2` to save time

So far, I'm seeing things like using *Draft release* but I feel it's not solving my issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but I would love to be disproved

Comment: It's breaking the "environment" concept, but I solved this by creating an extra environment just for running tests after deploy. Then you can redeploy just that environment if tests fail.

Comment: It is impossible. There is conditions for the task in build (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/process/conditions), but not available in release. As Daniel said that create a  draft release and disable unnecessary tasks.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers.  I think the condition in `build` that doesn't exist in `release` is the most promising thing now.  Daniel suggestion is one that I tried and it's a better than nothing but not optimal for my case.  I guess I'll continue to research a bit and post here any findings.

Comment: In my opinion, the draft release is better, you can clone the release definition and modify the new one per to the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rerun a release. However, you **can** create a draft release of the build in question and disable the steps you don't want to run prior to starting the deployment to an environment.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Daniel's answer I would look at creating more Release pipelines as needed. If your Build works and gives you the artifact you need, create more Release pipelines with the steps you need. This way you can have CD processes that run generally and on demand ones that occur when needed.

I think this way you can automate as much as possible. It's very easy and quick to create too so it's a good workaround until you get test reliability fixed.